# Ubuntu client awscli unsupported by AWS MSK Kafka?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, aws-msk

Are kafka commands through the awscli not supported in ubuntu?  Do we have to use 'Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type' for any consumers/producers interacting with MSK?

When we stood up an Ubuntu 18.04 instance it saying that

> awscli is already the newest version (1.14.44-1ubuntu1).

and `aws kafka help` shows:

> ubuntu@ip-xxxxxxxxx:~/kafka_2.12-2.1.0$ aws kafka help usage: aws
>   [options]   [ ...] [parameters] To
>   see help text, you can run:
>
> aws help   aws  help   aws   help aws:
>   error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
>
> acm                                      | alexaforbusiness apigateway
>   | application-autoscaling appstream                                |
>   appsync athena                                   | autoscaling
>   autoscaling-plans                        | batch budgets
>   | ce cloud9                                   | clouddirectory
>   cloudformation                           | cloudfront cloudhsm
>   | cloudhsmv2 cloudsearch                              |
>   cloudsearchdomain cloudtrail                               |
>   cloudwatch codebuild                                | codecommit
>   codepipeline                             | codestar cognito-identity
>   | cognito-idp cognito-sync                             | comprehend
>   cur                                      | datapipeline dax
>   | devicefarm directconnect                            | discovery dms 
>   | ds dynamodb                                 | dynamodbstreams ec2
>   | ecr ecs                                      | efs elasticache
>   | elasticbeanstalk elastictranscoder                        | elb
>   elbv2                                    | emr es
>   | events firehose                                 | gamelift glacier
>   | glue greengrass                               | guardduty health
>   | iam importexport                             | inspector iot
>   | iot-data iot-jobs-data                            | kinesis
>   kinesis-video-archived-media             | kinesis-video-media
>   kinesisanalytics                         | kinesisvideo kms
>   | lambda lex-models                               | lex-runtime
>   lightsail                                | logs machinelearning
>   | marketplace-entitlement marketplacecommerceanalytics             |
>   mediaconvert medialive                                | mediapackage
>   mediastore                               | mediastore-data
>   meteringmarketplace                      | mgh mobile
>   | mq mturk                                    | opsworks opsworkscm
>   | organizations pinpoint                                 | polly
>   pricing                                  | rds redshift
>   | rekognition resource-groups                          |
>   resourcegroupstaggingapi route53                                  |
>   route53domains sagemaker                                |
>   sagemaker-runtime sdb                                      |
>   serverlessrepo servicecatalog                           |
>   servicediscovery ses                                      | shield sms
>   | snowball sns                                      | sqs ssm
>   | stepfunctions storagegateway                           | sts support
>   | swf transcribe                               | translate waf
>   | waf-regional workdocs                                 | workmail
>   workspaces                               | xray s3api
>   | s3 configure                                | deploy configservice
>   | opsworks-cm runtime.sagemaker                        | history help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you installed `awscli` using `apt`. This will give you the version that the Ubuntu maintainers chose, which is going to be significantly behind the present.

To see just how far behind, you can run `aws --version`. Here's the output from a recently-updated installation:

```
> aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.153 Python/3.6.7 Linux/4.15.0-1037-aws botocore/1.12.143
```

I recommend running `apt remove awscli` to uninstall the version that comes from Ubuntu, and following [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-bundle.html) to install the latest distribution from AWS (this installs it in `/usr/local/bin` and requires that you have `sudo` access; if you just want to install it for your user you can use `pip` as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html).